# Starting application program at fix address in MSP430F2619

Tags: msp430, linker

I am writing firmware for system with boot loader and application using TI MSP430F2619 micro-controller.

I want to know How I can make sure my program restart at predefined address in flash let us say `0x3200.`

So that my boot loader will load the code and then jump to address 0x3200 for starting application code.

Below is my linker command file

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* lnk_msp430f2619.cmd - LINKER COMMAND FILE FOR LINKING MSP430F2619 PROGRAMS     */
/*                                                                            */
/*   Usage:  lnk430 <obj files...>    -o <out file> -m <map file> lnk.cmd     */
/*           cl430  <src files...> -z -o <out file> -m <map file> lnk.cmd     */
/*                                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* These linker options are for command line linking only.  For IDE linking,  */
/* you should set your linker options in Project Properties                   */
/* -c                                               LINK USING C CONVENTIONS  */
/* -stack  0x0100                                   SOFTWARE STACK SIZE       */
/* -heap   0x0100                                   HEAP AREA SIZE            */
/*                                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/****************************************************************************/
/* SPECIFY THE SYSTEM MEMORY MAP                                            */
/****************************************************************************/

MEMORY
{
    SFR                     : origin = 0x0000, length = 0x0010
    PERIPHERALS_8BIT        : origin = 0x0010, length = 0x00F0
    PERIPHERALS_16BIT       : origin = 0x0100, length = 0x0100
    RAM_MEM                 : origin = 0x1100, length = 0x0080
    RAM_BUFF                : origin = 0x1180, length = 0x0800
    RAM                     : origin = 0x1980, length = 0x0780
    INFOA                   : origin = 0x10C0, length = 0x0040
    INFOB                   : origin = 0x1080, length = 0x0040
    INFOC                   : origin = 0x1040, length = 0x0040
    INFOD                   : origin = 0x1000, length = 0x0040
    FLASH_BL                : origin = 0x2100, length = 0x1100
    FLASH                   : origin = 0x3200, length = 0xC600
    FLASH_BBT               : origin = 0xF800, length = 0x0400
    FLASH_MEM               : origin = 0xFC00, length = 0x00C0

    FLASH2                  : origin = 0x10400,length = 0xFC00
    INT00                   : origin = 0xFFC0, length = 0x0002
    INT01                   : origin = 0xFFC2, length = 0x0002
    INT02                   : origin = 0xFFC4, length = 0x0002
    INT03                   : origin = 0xFFC6, length = 0x0002
    INT04                   : origin = 0xFFC8, length = 0x0002
    INT05                   : origin = 0xFFCA, length = 0x0002
    INT06                   : origin = 0xFFCC, length = 0x0002
    INT07                   : origin = 0xFFCE, length = 0x0002
    INT08                   : origin = 0xFFD0, length = 0x0002
    INT09                   : origin = 0xFFD2, length = 0x0002
    INT10                   : origin = 0xFFD4, length = 0x0002
    INT11                   : origin = 0xFFD6, length = 0x0002
    INT12                   : origin = 0xFFD8, length = 0x0002
    INT13                   : origin = 0xFFDA, length = 0x0002
    INT14                   : origin = 0xFFDC, length = 0x0002
    INT15                   : origin = 0xFFDE, length = 0x0002
    INT16                   : origin = 0xFFE0, length = 0x0002
    INT17                   : origin = 0xFFE2, length = 0x0002
    INT18                   : origin = 0xFFE4, length = 0x0002
    INT19                   : origin = 0xFFE6, length = 0x0002
    INT20                   : origin = 0xFFE8, length = 0x0002
    INT21                   : origin = 0xFFEA, length = 0x0002
    INT22                   : origin = 0xFFEC, length = 0x0002
    INT23                   : origin = 0xFFEE, length = 0x0002
    INT24                   : origin = 0xFFF0, length = 0x0002
    INT25                   : origin = 0xFFF2, length = 0x0002
    INT26                   : origin = 0xFFF4, length = 0x0002
    INT27                   : origin = 0xFFF6, length = 0x0002
    INT28                   : origin = 0xFFF8, length = 0x0002
    INT29                   : origin = 0xFFFA, length = 0x0002
    INT30                   : origin = 0xFFFC, length = 0x0002
    RESET                   : origin = 0xFFFE, length = 0x0002
}

/****************************************************************************/
/* SPECIFY THE SECTIONS ALLOCATION INTO MEMORY                              */
/****************************************************************************/

SECTIONS
{
    .bss        : {} > RAM                /* GLOBAL & STATIC VARS              */
    .data       : {} > RAM                /* GLOBAL & STATIC VARS              */
    .sysmem     : {} > RAM                /* DYNAMIC MEMORY ALLOCATION AREA    */
    .stack      : {} > RAM (HIGH)         /* SOFTWARE SYSTEM STACK             */

    .text       : {}>> FLASH | FLASH2     /* CODE                              */
    .text:_isr  : {} > FLASH              /* ISR CODE SPACE                    */
    .text:_isr:_c_int00_noexit > 0x3200   /* application start address */
    .FLASHCODE : load = FLASH_MEM, run = RAM_MEM
    /* CODE IN FLASH AND WILL BE COPIED TO RAM AT EXECUTION HANDLED BY USER    */
    .RAMCODE   : load = FLASH_MEM         /* CODE WILL BE IN RAM               */
    .ram_buff   : {} > RAM_BUFF           /* reserved big ram buffer */

    .cinit      : {} > FLASH              /* INITIALIZATION TABLES             */
//#ifdef (__LARGE_DATA_MODEL__)
    .const      : {} > FLASH | FLASH2     /* CONSTANT DATA                     */
//#else
//    .const      : {} > FLASH              /* CONSTANT DATA                   */
//#endif
    .cio        : {} > RAM                /* C I/O BUFFER                      */

    .pinit      : {} > FLASH              /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
    .init_array : {} > FLASH              /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
    .mspabi.exidx : {} > FLASH            /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
    .mspabi.extab : {} > FLASH            /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */

    .infoA     : {} > INFOA              /* MSP430 INFO FLASH MEMORY SEGMENTS */
    .infoB     : {} > INFOB
    .infoC     : {} > INFOC
    .infoD     : {} > INFOD
    .flash_bl  : {} > FLASH_BL          /* Reserved for boot loader */
    .flash_bbt : {} > FLASH_BBT         /* reserved for flash bad block table */

    /* MSP430 INTERRUPT VECTORS          */
    RESERVED0    : { * ( .int00 ) } > INT00 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED1    : { * ( .int01 ) } > INT01 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED2    : { * ( .int02 ) } > INT02 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED3    : { * ( .int03 ) } > INT03 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED4    : { * ( .int04 ) } > INT04 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED5    : { * ( .int05 ) } > INT05 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED6    : { * ( .int06 ) } > INT06 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED7    : { * ( .int07 ) } > INT07 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED8    : { * ( .int08 ) } > INT08 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED9    : { * ( .int09 ) } > INT09 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED10   : { * ( .int10 ) } > INT10 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED11   : { * ( .int11 ) } > INT11 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED12   : { * ( .int12 ) } > INT12 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED13   : { * ( .int13 ) } > INT13 type = VECT_INIT
    DAC12        : { * ( .int14 ) } > INT14 type = VECT_INIT
    DMA          : { * ( .int15 ) } > INT15 type = VECT_INIT
    USCIAB1TX    : { * ( .int16 ) } > INT16 type = VECT_INIT
    USCIAB1RX    : { * ( .int17 ) } > INT17 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT1        : { * ( .int18 ) } > INT18 type = VECT_INIT
    PORT2        : { * ( .int19 ) } > INT19 type = VECT_INIT
    RESERVED20   : { * ( .int20 ) } > INT20 type = VECT_INIT
    ADC12        : { * ( .int21 ) } > INT21 type = VECT_INIT
    USCIAB0TX    : { * ( .int22 ) } > INT22 type = VECT_INIT
    USCIAB0RX    : { * ( .int23 ) } > INT23 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMERA1      : { * ( .int24 ) } > INT24 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMERA0      : { * ( .int25 ) } > INT25 type = VECT_INIT
    WDT          : { * ( .int26 ) } > INT26 type = VECT_INIT
    COMPARATORA  : { * ( .int27 ) } > INT27 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMERB1      : { * ( .int28 ) } > INT28 type = VECT_INIT
    TIMERB0      : { * ( .int29 ) } > INT29 type = VECT_INIT
    NMI          : { * ( .int30 ) } > INT30 type = VECT_INIT
    .reset       : {}               > RESET  /* MSP430 RESET VECTOR         */ 
}

/****************************************************************************/
/* INCLUDE PERIPHERALS MEMORY MAP                                           */
/****************************************************************************/

-l msp430f2619.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

The startaddress of the MSP430 is stored at location 0xFFFE, which is in your linker file as RESET vector.

You have to set a constant value to your startaddress and tell the linker to put it to `.reset`. `.reset` is a section defined to placed at RESET in your linker file.
How you do that depends on what language and compiler/linker you use.

I'm not 100% sure if that is what you want though, as your question contains something about a bootloader. If you mean that the MSP430 starts in a boot part using the RESET vector and then you want to jump from there to your application part the approach is of course different.

In one application we stored two important values at a given address in the flash memory: the initial stack pointer and the start address of the application part (in your case that would be 0x3200 I assume).

Then the bootpart would load the stack pointer and then jump to the main part. Doing that from C++ can be a bit unintuitive:

```
(reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void)>(0x3200))();  //lint !e923 startaddress has to be casted to function pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

The [user guide of your processor](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F2619/technicaldocuments) says in section 2.1.2:

> Program counter (PC) is loaded with address contained at reset vector location (0FFFEh).

Your linker command file defines the section `.reset` for this value.